# Can a django model have unique and a shared non unique field?

Tags: django

I have a model with a `CharField` with `max_length=16` called `verify_key`:

```
verify_key = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=16)
```

The purpose of this field is to be a unique, 16 character alphanumeric identifier. When a user registers, they are sent this code, they return this code and their verified status is set to true.

In the unlikely event that two users somehow manage to generate the same key, the latest won't be able to register. What I would like to do when a user registers is set their `verify_key` to be an empty string. I can't do this with the unique parameter. How do I fix this or is there a better method?

Comment: https://github.com/mfogel/django-simple-email-confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `null=True` on the field and set the field to `None`. A column with a `UNIQUE` constraint can have multiple `NULL` values.

You'll have to be explicit when using forms or default values. The default for a `CharField` is an empty string, and empty form values will also be saved as an empty string. In both cases you need to explicitly set the value to `None` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
import uuid   
verify_key = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                              unique=True,
                              default=uuid.uuid4)
```

If you are using django 1.8 you also have `UUIDField`. Here's [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.UUIDField).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in your model class.

You just need to add `null=True` to the field and set `Model.verify_key=None` whenever you create an instance. Also, you can define a custom model form to deal with this in the forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an empty string, but you can set the value to NULL. NULL is not equals to NULL when Django check for uniqueness.